# Validating Form Data For null values in web api

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api, data-annotations, form-data, system.componentmodel

I have class like

```
public class MyClass
{
  public object Jobj{get; set;}
  public string summary{get; set;}

 public string someMethod()
 {
  //Do some work
  return "";
 }
}
```

and a post action creating instance of this class and initialising properties with form data inputs

```
        [HttpPost]
        public dynamic controllerAction()
        {
            try
            {
                var instance= new MyClass
                {
                    Jobj= JObject.Parse(HttpContext.Current.Request.Params["formInputKey1"]),
                    summary= HttpContext.Current.Request.Params["summaryKey"]
                };
                return instance.SomeMethod();
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                return ex;
            }
        }
```

I wanted to know how to enforce null property check for form-data input

What I tried:

```
public class MyClass
{
  [Required]
  public object Jobj{get; set;}
  [Required(AllowEmptyStrings = false), StringLength(maximumLength: 100, MinimumLength = 1)]
  public string summary{get; set;}

 public string someMethod()
 {
  //Do some work
  return "";
 }
}
```

and a post action creating instance of this class and initialising properties with form data inputs

```
        [HttpPost]
        public dynamic controllerAction()
        {
            try
            {
                var instance= new MyClass
                {
                    Jobj= JObject.Parse(HttpContext.Current.Request.Params["formInputKey1"]),
                    summary= HttpContext.Current.Request.Params["summaryKey"]
                };
                var isModelStateValid = ModelState.IsValid;
                if(!isModelStateValid )
                {
                   throw ArgumentException("Found Data Null");
                }
                return instance.SomeMethod();
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                return ex;
            }
        }
```

But `ModelState.IsValid` is always true as it was containing count = 0

Comment: It looks like model binding error. Your action method must take MyClass like **controllerAction(MyClass myClass)** to check your model status that it comes from view part. Also you can share your view part code?

Comment: It don't have view part code. We are using FormData to avoid script kind tags in json data, so i can't take it like **controllerAction(MyClass myClass)**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In order to use `ModelState.IsValid`, if speaking simply, you should use the object as parameter to the method

```
public dynamic controllerAction(MyClass x)
```

`ModelState.IsValid`, again, if put simply, is populated by `ModelBinder` (basically a thing that "serializes" your Action arguments), not just by `JObject.parse` or anything like that.

Then if you cannot use default `ModelBinder` you can write your own - https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/mvc/advanced/custom-model-binding?view=aspnetcore-5.0
(this link is for .NET 5, but basically the same thing and idea is valid for old MVC/WebApi as well)

Alternatively if you still want to use your code, you can simply trigger default validation using `Validator` class:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.componentmodel.dataannotations.validator?view=net-5.0

It throws the exception if object is not valid according to attributes you defined.